React app makes REST api requests to the wrong URL when using a windows server proxy
I'm hosting a Springboot app with a React frontend on a windows server by running the jar on it. The apps DNS gets resolved to "app.local". This works fine in my company's local network. The App and api share the same url so every time a request gets send it goes to "app.local/api/...".
To use the App outside our local network a proxy was installed which forwards "app.msappproxy.net" into our local web server. The app is reachable trough the proxy. The problem is request to the api still get send to "app.local/api/..." instead of "app.msappproxy.net/api/..." and therefor doesn't get resolved because this domain doesn't exist outside of the local network.
I wasn't part of creating the configs for this app and don't have a deep knowledge of this but I believe there is probably an easy react or spring boot config to tell the app to use it's domain or proxy. Sadly I'm not able to find something about this online until know.
I only found https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ but I'm not sure if this applies for my use case. As its only mentioning development and one proxy. I want to be able to use the proxy address outside of the network and the normal address inside of the network. The problem is probably our config.tsx which gives the api path based on a config.json which has the url hard coded:
/* Configuration
 *  Reads values from .env file if present otherwise an environment variable must be configured.
 * */
let currentConfig = require(`./config.json`);

export const config = {
  apiURL: "/api",
  serverBaseURL: currentConfig.serverBaseURL,
};

export function getAPIPath(endpoint: string) {
  return config.serverBaseURL + config.apiURL + endpoint;
}

export function getBreakPoints() {

  return {
    values: {
      xs: 0, // phone
      sm: 600, // tablets
      md: 1025, // small laptop 900 -> 1025 d.h Mobile Version < md
      lg: 1200, // desktop
      xl: 1536, // large screens
    }
  }
}

export default config;

Any help is welcomed, thanks!
